# Webview inside a Viewpager with horizontal seekbar

Tags: android, webview, seekbar, android-viewpager

I m unable to find any solution to have a horizontal seekbar inside a webview in a Viewpager. The slider inside the webview has been very erratic as a large swipe leads to page swipe and scroll on the seekbar is not recognised.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will ever get this to work well, as there are too many things competing for horizontal swipe events.